# Remove a stream from `futures::stream::SelectAll`

Tags: rust, stream, future

Is it possible to remove a stream after it has been bundled together with other streams into a single stream by [futures::stream::select_all](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html)?

Something like this:

```rust
use futures::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;

let mut bundled = stream::select_all(vec![
        stream::repeat("a"),
        stream::repeat("b"),
        stream::repeat("c"),
    ]);

if let Some(x) = bundled.next().await {
    if x == "b" {
        bundled.remove_at(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say no, it isn't. But it's hard to be sure because your question doesn't include any detail whatsoever, so it's highly likely that I have misunderstood part of what you are asking. A [reprex] will help!

Comment: Added sample code to clarify the intent, thanks @PeterHall

Comment: Under what condition would you want to remove the stream? Presumably not immediately, since you could have just not added it in the first place.

Comment: For example, do you want to remove it based on some value in one of the streams, or based on some external event? Could you update the code to show a more realistic use case - as you've written it, the answer is just to not add the stream at all.

Comment: In this case, I have a vector of TcpStreams. I want to read data from them as and when they become available, where a combination of `select_all` and `ready_chunk` work well. However, on a user initiated connection termination (or based on another condition) I want to remove a TcpStream

Comment: In this specific case, I didn't need to use `select_all` at all, instead i used tokio::spawn to concurently process connections as shown here https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/fn.spawn.html#examples